# Python, create database connectors and have threads to use connectors

Tags: python, sql, python-multithreading, snowflake-connector

I have a database that I connect to but queries take 30s to get back a response. I'm making about 50 queries each time I want to generate a report. This will take 25mins to get my report generated and is not ideal. The most I can currently do is use threads to execute my query in batches of 10 with 10 database connections. I'm fairly new to python so I'm having a hard time finding resources for this specific task. I'm using snowflake-connector to create connections to my database. Since the most connections I can use is 10. I know I have to create a class to handle these connections but I can't figure out the logic in Python to know when a connector is ready to be used to then attach it to a thread to execute a query on the connector. I'm not sure how to handle the main thread as it's waiting for connections to finish executing their query. Do I use sleep or wait on the main thread. Should I use a while loop on the main thread to check if the connectors are ready? Should I store these connectors as instances of a class?

If anyone has examples they can share or any resources to help me figure this out would be greatly appreciated. I'm fairly new to threading in general and coming from a Java background, my approach in Python is just using a class but I'm not sure if this approach is "pythonic"

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have so far? Also if you're trying to wait until the threads finish, and have no other tasks for the main thread, then use `thread.join()`. Take a look at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) for a good tutorial on how threads work in Python, including how to synchronize tasks.

Comment: Sadly at the moment, I don't, each time I try coding something out I get confused. I already have py files with the logic I want to do with the queried data, the snowflake connection, and a query generator. I'm just struggling to put it all into threads and have those threads launch in batches but each time a thread finishes, I'd prefer it to pick up another query rather than use a join and wait for all other threads to finish before launching another batch of 10.

Comment: Instead of trying to generate a new thread after each thread finishes, why don't you use the same thread and just start a new query? You could generate 10 threads that start a task, the task creates a query and once it's finished it keeps repeating until there are no more queries left to do.